# django - does not save to database immediately

Tags: python, django

another newbie question,

Right after I save an item to database, I tried to access
its primary key to redirect its page. But I could not get it done. 
I tried manually handling the transaction as it explains in this [document](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django/en/1.2.4/topics/db/transactions.html).

Could that be because of using admin mode?

I get this error :

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

I changed the line of return to this to convert id to string

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/page/"+str(page.id)+"/")
```

here is the code segment.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def new_post_save(request):
    .
    .
    .
    page.save()  
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/page/"+page.id+"/")
```

here is the rest of the original view and the model

```
def new_post_save(request):
page_name =  request.POST["page_name"]
content =  request.POST["content"]
postCategory = request.POST["cat"]

page = BlogPost(title = page_name,body = content, author = request.user, category = postCategory)

page.save()  
return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/page/"+page.id+"/")
```

the model

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
body = models.TextField()
category = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='other')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

here base.py I guess I did not override the save function.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    """
    Saves the current instance. Override this in a subclass if you want to
    control the saving process.

    The 'force_insert' and 'force_update' parameters can be used to insist
    that the "save" must be an SQL insert or update (or equivalent for
    non-SQL backends), respectively. Normally, they should not be set.
    """
    if force_insert and force_update:
        raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.")
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)

    save.alters_data = True
```

in settings.py by database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'blog.db',                      
        'USER': '',                     
        'PASSWORD': '',                 
        'HOST': '',                    
        'PORT': '',                    
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to do anything with transactions here. What was your original code?

Comment: What are the errors you got when trying the old approach, and the new one?

Comment: in debug mode, when I reach the line of return,  page.id is None. There is no difference between old approach and the new one, for both page.id is none.

Comment: If the object truly saved, it would have an id immediately accessible. Did you happen to override the `save` method? For some reason, the object isn't actually being saved, but without more code it's impossible to tell why.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks, I added save function up there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `id` field from your Model class.

Django will insert an AutoField called `id` automatically if you don't specify a primary key, so you don't need it.

Because you have specifically said that *your* `id` field is an integer primary key, Django is expecting you to manage it yourself. It's an `IntField`, as you declared, not an `AutoField`, so it is not automatically assigned any value.

Comment: thanks , I will try it but have another question. if I delete the id field, how can I redirect using blogpost object's primary key?

Comment: If you don't include a primary key field in your model definition, Django will add one. It will be called 'id', and will be an auto-incrementing integer field.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of manually calling save()

> page = BlogPost.objects.create(title = page_name,body = content,
>   author = request.user, category = postCategory)

Comment: create did not work neither. the same as save(), it adds to database but not immediately.